# When may a person take down his Succah?

Tags: halacha, sukkot, sukkah, chol-hamoed

When can I take down my Succah?

Suppose that after Chol HaMoed begins one is traveling for an extended period and would not like to leave the decorations, s'chach and sides up because they are likely to be damaged by the weather.

Are there any rules about taking down a Succah during Succos?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10657/why-dont-we-say-tachanun-at-mincha-on-erev-shabbat-or-erev-yom-tov/18666#18666

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10591/taking-down-sukkah-decorations-before-the-end-of-holiday

Comment: I suspect others have heard of opening two doors on one side of a 4 door car, and placing Schachter over the top to form a tiny sukkah. If one was barred from taking down such a sukkah, how could anyone do this? Does the car become muktze and assur b'hanaah as some answers suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You can not take your succah down till after shmini atzeres in Israel and in the diaspora after simchas torah. This is unanimously agreed in the Shulchan aruch orach chaim 638,1:

עצי סוכה אסורים כל שמונת ימי החג, בין עצי דפנות בין עצי סכך. (ואפילו קיסם לחצוץ בו שיניו אסור) (מהרי"ל). ואין נאותין מהן לדבר אחר כל שמונת הימים מפני שיום השביעי כולו הסוכה מוקצה עד בין השמשות והואיל והוקצה לבין השמשות של שביעי הוקצה לכל היום- The wood ( or any material used) of the succah are forbidden all 8 days of the festival whether the walls or the sechach, even a toothpick. One is not allowed to have benefit for anything else even on shmini atzeres (or simchas tora in chutz laaretz*) where there is no longer a use of the succah since it was already prohibited beforehand it remains mukza for the entire 8th day (or ninth in diaspora).

הגה: ואפילו נפלה הסוכה -- אסורים, ולא מהני בה תנאי -טור. '- And even if the succah fell down, the material is forbidden and a stipulation (to be able to use the wood from beforehand) does not help.       Even if you take it down not for your benifit the wood is mukza (cannot be moved whatsoever)as it says explicitly in tosfos succah 9b minayin:בפ' המביא כדי יין (ביצה דף ל: ושם) מייתי דרשה דהכא ואפילו הכי משמע התם בסוף שמעתין דלא אסירא אלא מטעם מוקצה דקאמרינן עצי סוכה דחיילא קדושה איתקצאי לשבעה

However a stipulation from before Succos helps with regards to food or drink e.g fruits hanging for decoration to use them to eat when ever one wants but if he did not stipulate they are forbiddon all 8/9 days.

S.A O.C 638,2: אכן אוכלים ומשקים שתולין בסוכה כדי לנאותה -- אסור להסתפק מהם כל שמונה, אפילו נפלו.    (וביום טוב ושבת אסור לטלטלם דמוקצים הם) (טור).

ואם התנה עליהם בשעה שתלאם ואמר "איני בודל מהן כל בין השמשות" (של שמונה ימים) (בית יוסף בשם אורחות חיים) -- הרי זה מסתפק מהם בכל עת שירצה שהרי לא הקצה אותם ולא חל עליהם קדושת הסוכה ולא נחשבו כמותה. The stipulation said is "I will not be separated from the decorations the whole of Bein hashmoshos( the time when Yom Tov commences).

*The source that the diaspora is forbidden to use the material of the succah 9 days is the Mishna brura explaining the Shulchan Oruch 'שמונת - ולדידן גם  בט'

Comment: What does a prohibition of benefit have to do with taking then down? Do you benefit from the stuff as you take it down?

Comment: even if you take it down not for your benifit the wood is mukza as it says explicitly in tosfos succah 9b minayin:בפ' המביא כדי יין (ביצה דף ל: ושם) מייתי דרשה דהכא ואפילו הכי משמע התם בסוף שמעתין דלא אסירא אלא מטעם מוקצה דקאמרינן עצי סוכה דחיילא קדושה איתקצאי לשבעה

Comment: So when you say "This is unanimously agreed in the Shulchan aruch" you mean "This is my Diyuk in a Tosfos"

Comment: yes it is unanimously agreed as said in shulchan oruch brought down והואיל והוקצה לבין השמשות של שביעי הוקצה לכל היום its clear it was muktza all 7 days which is why it stretches to the 8th

Answer (score 0):

In answering the question, "Is it possible to take down a Sukkah over Chol Hamoed...Should I take it down during Chol Hamoed or should I leave it there with the possibility that it may be destroyed?" Rabbi Yirmiyohu Kaganoff [writes](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=4168), "You may take [the sukka] down if you are concerned it will be destroyed."

Regarding the second half of your question, See [here](http://library.yctorah.org/lindenbaum/may-one-take-down-a-sukkah-on-chol-hamoed-in-anticipation-of-hurricane-joaquin/) for a full discussion: "Rabbenu Yehonasan on the Rif explains taking down the sukkah early would be ביזוי מצוה. While the Ikrei HaDaas (OC 2:68) gives arguments both to forbid and permit taking down a sukkah on Chol HaMoed, the Li’horos Nosson (7:47-49), Rav Nosson Geshtenter concludes that it is permissible to dismantle a sukkah on Chol HaMoed. "